# When to use random tokens to prevent XSS?

Tags: security, web

This isn't a language specific question, but I am using PHP5.

I am working on a project that has some amount of PII. Legally we are required to secure this data from hacking attempts, and because of that I have been researching best practices for defending common attack types. Obviously all database calls are using parameterized queries, and all data provided by the user is sanitized to prevent injection. I have also implemented sessions and methods to prevent session hijacking.

When it comes to defending against XSS attacks on forms, best practice seems to be to include a hidden input with a form token, then after the post to check the tokens match. There are further ways to make this more secure.

I have imagined one type of attack and haven't found a solution for it. What if a malicious site loads a hidden iframe pointed at my site (eg, view-member.php?id=1234) and because the victim user is logged into my site, their session continues in that iframe. What is stopping this malicious site from iterating through the IDs and ripping the data to get ahold of PII? Should I be creating a unique token for each page view, and checking that token when the page loads?

I am not 100% sure, but assuming my site is using HTTPS, the browser should warn the user and/or prevent the connection. Is that correct? Is that enough security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, everytime you present a form or any kind of interaction, you should include a randomized, verifiable piece of information that changes every time. This is not for preventing XSS but CSRF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

The main problem is: An attacker can just send automated requests to your input-handling script without going through the "pain" of filling in your form manually (or even visit your page).

However, you won't prevent XSS attacks with this technique, as XSS attacks are mainly user input containing executable code (javascript) that is not filtered by the input validation. So to prevent XSS as well, you should always make sure not to deliver unfiltered user-generated content anywhere.

HTTPS won't help you in either case unless you use client-side certificates that allow access to your website only from trusted clients. HTTPS mainly acts as a transmission scrambler and identity verifier but does not prevent a bot from sending valid (but malicious) data to your form.

Hosting a website in an iFrame does not grant the attacker the permission to read cookies or information from the target page (that would be awful) as long as you follow the same-origin policy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

With this, only domains you whitelist will get access to information hosted on your page.

Comment: You are right, its not XSS. My apologies on misused terminology.

But my question is, what about simply displaying information? Do I need to use a token to validate that the real user requested to view that page (and not some script that is exploiting a logged in user)?

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe that helps you understand better

Comment: Assume there is a page, view-member.php, that displays some PII to a logged in user. The information can be updated on a post, but it can simply be read without posting. I am imagining an offsite malicious page which loads a hidden iframe to my view-member.php?id=1234 to exploit a cross site user who is logged in. The goal is not for them to post any information, but simply to rip the data from the requested page, thus obtaining the PII.

Comment: The easiest way to test a possible scenario is to set it up and test it. You can use different domains (using your hosts-file) and try it out.

Comment: After reading your link about Same Origin Policy, I realize what I worried about cannot possibly happen. Thank you for the response.